# H2 database Merge into based on one column

Tags: h2

I want to update or insert into this table dataTime if the loginId already exists else insert

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserLastActivity 
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    loginId VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    dataTime BIGINT NOT NULL,
);
```

First attempt:

```
MERGE INTO UserLastActivity KEY(loginId) VALUES(#{loginId}, #{dataTime})
```

For the above statement I get exception stating number of columns mismatch

Second attempt:

```
MERGE INTO UserLastActivity KEY(loginId) (loginId, dataTime)
VALUES(#{loginId}, #{dataTime})
```

I get exception

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "MERGE INTO USERLASTACTIVITY KEY(LOGINID) (LOGINID[*], DATATIME) VALUES(?, ?) "; expected "(, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- It's safer to specify the column names, like you would do on any `INSERT`.
- You need to specify a value for `loginId` since it's declared `NOT NULL`.

  ```
  MERGE INTO UserLastActivity (id, loginId, dataTime) 
    KEY(loginId) 
    VALUES(10, 'user1', 1234);
  ```

Comment: id is auto increment i will not able to be able to pass the value

Comment: If you don't pass the value of `id`, then the `MERGE` doesn't make sense. That would become an `INSERT` 100% of the time. Can you clarify?

Comment: It is throwing error saying parameter don't match so i left the merge option and went with update and insert. If update return 0 rows then insert